# importing a csv file with clean columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, format

so i'm trying to import this csv file and each value is seperated by a comma but how do i make new rows and columns from the imported data?

I tried importing it as normal and printing the data frame in different ways.

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not include screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), instead: copy all error messages and code into the body of the question.

Comment: please post a sample from the csv file

Comment: @bn_ln sample below: 
 PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S

Answer (score 0):

try the same with

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', sep = ',')
```

this might work